# Should I be allowed to review a question for reopening when I wielded Mjölnir to close it?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was working on the Reopen Review queue (looking at duplicates specifically) and was asked to review [Writing a function to work with a variable number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16112694?filter-closereason=duplicate).

I closed that question as the duplicate of [An example of use of varargs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784729/an-example-of-use-of-varargs-in-c).  Although other people had suggested other duplicates, by the time I wielded Mjölnir on the question, I was 'working alone'.

Why was I asked to review this?

I think I should not have been given the option of reviewing it since I was responsible for the closure.  Even if other people had been involved, I'm not convinced I should have been given the review because I was involved in the closure.  (I stand by the close reason I gave — I think the recent question is a duplicate of the other.  I also skipped the reopen review, to avoid appearance of 'conflict of interest'.  But I don't think I should have been given the option to appear to have a conflict of interest.)

Comment: But you're probably the perfect person to be served the review _because_ you're the person that unilateraly closed it.

Comment: It isn't easy getting something reopened. When appealing a decision that was made by a single person, it would be more fair to have multiple people involved. I think it was good that you skipped the review, and I agree that you shouldn't even have been given it.

Comment: I don't agree so much that you answered the question *and* closed it as a duplicate, though.

Comment: It's easier to answer that question than to find a decent duplicate.  That's often the case; duplicate finding is very hard.

Comment: Then delete the answer after you found the duplicate...

Comment: No thanks.  My answer is valid.  That the question is also a duplicate doesn't mean it can't be answered.

Comment: The purpose of closing questions is to prevent answers. Answering and closing subverts that system.

Comment: Off-topic: perhaps it would be a good idea to create something similar to [C++-FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) for C? I know that this kind of goes against the SO system, but since that system doesn't work, it would be a helpful moderator tool. I can easily toss out 50 or so canonical duplicate links for C myself. It's stupid that every gold badge user has to sit and hoard their own duplicate links when we could be sharing them and minimize the time searching for duplicates.

Comment: @Lundin: One problem I can see with adding a (currently hypothetical) [tag:c-faq] tag to some questions is that some of them already have a full complement of tags and displacing one to add the C-FAQ tag would lose potentially useful information.  I wonder if we need to create a C FAQ question which has one Community Wiki answer with links appropriate questions?  This avoids the 'tag overflow' problem — but isn't as dynamic as simply tagging a question.  (See my profile to discuss by email.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I went ahead and posted a formal proposal for this. Please share your thoughts: [Creating a C FAQ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349241/creating-a-c-faq-tag).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Had a re-open review been something like "I'm contesting the reason why this was closed" then perhaps it would have been unsuitable if the person who closed it gets to review it.

But this is not how re-open reviews work. They pop up after changes are made to a closed question. The changes may or may not address the reason why the question was closed. The review is on the changes - in this case, do the changes mean that the question isn't duplicate any longer?

There is no reason why you wouldn't be able to do that review - in fact, you are probably the most suitable person to do it.

---

As for the specific question, the OP edited it so that it now asks a different question. It is no longer a duplicate, but this is not a good edit, since there are already answers posted that answered the original question. I reviewed the re-open vote and declined it for this reason, then prompted the OP to ask a new question instead.