# Tag wiki preview looks ok, live changes look crap

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, markdown-rendering

We're adding a FAQ to the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). I initially did this with a copy/paste from a meta post to the wiki.

The [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349261/584518) looks ok even though it only contained raw URL to the posts. The site replaced them with titles automatically.

During the preview of the tag wiki, everything looked fine too. But during live posing, the URLs are not replaced with titles. This difference between preview and live post seems to be a bug.

(If this is yet another case where caching is the culprit then ignore this question.)

---

To make things complicated, apparently there are 3 different ways to post a link:

- Just copy/paste raw URL. Seems to work fine sometimes. Sometimes not.
- `[Description here](www.something.com)`. Works fine but involves manual work.
- A special format for tag wikis (?): `[Description here][number]`. Works fine but involves even more manual work.

Comment: FYI - the "special format", a.k.a. reference links, is not specific to wikis; it's standard Markdown syntax. Nor does the reference need to be a number. See for example the edit I just made to this post, converting your "meta post" link. I'm aware that this is in no way helpful towards your actual question.

Comment: Worth noting: I edited the second FAQ link on that page ("Is char signed or unsigned by default?") to use `https://` instead of `http://`, and the title now shows up as expected.

Comment: @PaulRoub Indeed, https seems to be the culprit! This allows me to fix the post quickly. But there is probably some bug here related to https that needs to be resolved...?

Comment: Possibly. I'm just commenting re: what I noticed; someone with actual knowledge and authority would need to answer WRT whether or not this behavior is intended.

Comment: I have now fixed the linked wiki to use https, but please check edit history to track the bug.